# Looking for USB-C hub with USB-C port for Power Delivery *and* USB-C port for video output

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for a USB-C hub/dongle with two USB-C ports that support Power Delivery charging and USB-C 4K video output.

I'm connecting my 16" MBP to an LG 4K monitor via a USB-C to DisplayPort cable; however, the LG doesn't return sufficient power to charge the MBP. So I need one USB-C port for connecting to the monitor and the other USB-C port for connecting to the MBP charger. Of course, the hub/dongle needs to have a few USB Type-A ports, too.

The second USB-C port on every hub/dongle I've seen so far can only be used for data transfer. Is this a limitation of the USB specification?
Or is it a rare use-case and not enough vendors out there building such hubs?